# jest test table rows and columns

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

I have a html table with the following data:

---

id | name

### 2  | C

### 1  | B

### 3  | A

I need to test the order of table items.
I can get the rows using:

```
wrapper.findAll('table tr')
```

But how can I assert the order of rows comparing the columns (tds) ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
let $rows = wrapper.findAll('tbody > tr').wrappers

let column1 = $rows.map(row => {
  return row.
    findAll('td')
    .at(0)
    .text()
})

expect(column1[0]).toBe('text 1')
expect(column1[1]).toBe('text 2')
```